# Why does svn checkout use the wrong directory?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins 1.568.

I have a multi-configuration project setup. I simply added an axis "target" with the values "debug" and "release".

I added Subversion source code management and configured it to check-out to a certain subfolder under the custom workspace directory.

However, when I trigger a build, Jenkins starts checking out the svn repo into a folder "target/debug" (or "target/release") under the custom workspace directory. I want both the debug and release configuration to be built inside the single repository that I specified under the "Source Code Management" configuration item.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I found someone reporting the same issue, but it doesn't seem to have been picked up: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17934?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I (accidentally) bumped into a raised ticket for this "issue", I found out that the "Directory for sub-builds" advanced project option is the solution for this problem. It doesn't have a "question mark" next to it so there's no explanation about that setting. But after some googling I found out that if you put "." there, it will use the same repository for all builds, which is exactly what I want.

Jenkins ticket reference:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8317

Answer (score 1):

> Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

You are using multi-configuration project.

A multi-configuration project has separate sub-workspaces under the main `$WORKSPACE` for each axis, `target/debug` and `target/release` in your case.

When you are specifying a custom workspace, that is for the main `$WORKSPACE` location, and it **does** use that, but since it is a multi-configuration project, it then creates those sub-workspace folders, and checks out the code into each.

You could try using `../../` in front of your SVN local folder name, but I don't know if that would work. In any case, you are breaking Jenkins' design for multi-configuration project setup. It relies on workspaces being separate.

If you really want to save on the extra checkout, consider having a separate job that does a single SVN checkout, and then triggers the multi-configuration job. The multi-configuration job would still need to reference the workspace through `../../` (if that even works)

Comment: Ok, thanks.
I thought this would be the answer, but I consider it a flaw in the Jenkins multi-configuration design, because it makes no sense to have a separate checkout for every configuration. Checkouts should be coupled to the top-level project description and not to a build configuration. (But then again, you also have people that have separate SVN repositories for separate targets - which I consider a break in simplicity).
On topic: I will try your last idea or if that doesn't work use separate project definitions per target (using the same svn repo)